# "Import "youtube_dl" could not be resolved" Using virtual environment / pip, all other imports work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, youtube-dl

[screenShot of vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlAzx.png)

A screenshot of my visual studio code is above in the link ^.

I have a virtual env running in the terminal in vsc. I have the vsc python interpreter set to python 3.10.7. I have been using pip to install dependencies. All other dependencies work, ie flask, tensorflow, numpy, etc. But youtube_dl says it cannot be resolved. It is installed in the location shown: **c:\users\user\onedrive\desktop\projectName\.venv\lib\site-packages**

Any idea why this is not resolving?

I have tried doing pip install youtube_dl within the virtual env. I have tried it without of the virtual env, I have tried using python3 -m pip install youtube_dl. Not sure why this won't resolve.

Comment: After installing in virtualenv, did you run the program within the virtualenv?

Comment: Yes I did, same issue

Comment: I assume you are installing it in an environment and trying to run the python script from other environment. Please mention the process you've followed.

Comment: I activated the virtual env on the integrated vsc terminal, then in that env I installed youtube_dl via  “pip install youtube_dl” and then I ran the python file in that same env via “py app.py”

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Python 3.10.7 in the lower right corner is not consistent with the python version you understand.

It is Python Interpreter instead of python version.

This problem is caused by the wrong python interpreter. You installed the package in the `.venv` environment and run the file at the base environment.

The solution is using shorcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and typing "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your `.venv` environment. (You can also click Python 3.10.7 in the lower right corner).

Answer (score 0):

You Can click on the "3.10.7 64-bit" and vscode will show you selected python environment and then make sure that the chose env is your '.venv'.

You can also run you code on terminal with activated .venv and there should not be a Problem.